# Dynamically create js Array filled with certain value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering if there is a way to create javascript/jquery array in **one-liner** to receive something like:

```
my_array = ['-', '-', ,'-' ,'-']
```

Idea is that array should be created with dynamic length and all values filled with given value.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```js
var total = 4;
var my_array = new Array(total + 1).join("-").split("");

document.write(JSON.stringify(my_array))
```

[.fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) Support The native function will be added in (ECMAScript 6), but for now is not available.

```
if(!Array.prototype.fill){
    Array.prototype.fill = function(val){
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
            this[i] = val
        }
        return this
    }
}

var my_array = new Array(4).fill("-"); //returns ["-","-","-","-"]
```

Comment: This only works if you want to fill the array with a single character string. Try switching `"-"` to `"abc"` to see what I mean.

Comment: It is why the "downvote" ?. Reason: Question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
Array.apply(null, new Array(63)).map(String.prototype.valueOf,"-")
```